# How do I extract a key with varying names following a pattern in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have to match ids from a json object where the key can be authority_123, authority_111 etc.
How do I get to check authoriy_* in my query below. It is part of a dynamic query in plpgsql.
The * in bottom query can be any integer.

```
if json_array_length(tms_hlpr_usr_has_authority_fr_srvc_requests(usr_id_,org_id_)) > 0 then
        _extra_where = _extra_where || 
            ' and ' || quote_literal(usr_id_) || '  =  srvc_req.form_data->>$$authority_*$$ and srvc_req.is_deleted is not true ';
    end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

```
create or replace function get_json_keys() returns void as $$

    declare
        rec record;
        tmp_key text;
        tmp_counter integer;

    BEGIN
    create temp table tmp_table(
        id serial primary key,
        json_data json
    );

    insert into tmp_table(json_data) values('{"key1":"John", "keya":30}');
    insert into tmp_table(json_data) values('{"key2":"Mary", "keyb":28}');
    insert into tmp_table(json_data) values('{"key3":"Peter", "keyc":38}');

    for rec in select * from tmp_table
    loop
        tmp_counter:=0;
        RAISE NOTICE 'rec.id: %', rec.id;
        for tmp_key in select json_object_keys(rec.json_data)
        loop
            RAISE NOTICE '  keys[%]: %', tmp_counter,tmp_key;
            tmp_counter:=tmp_counter+1;
        end loop;
    end loop;

    raise notice '%', (select array_agg(key) from (select json_object_keys(json_data) as key from tmp_table) sub);

    drop table tmp_table;
END $$ language plpgsql;

select get_json_keys();
```

This will output

```
rec.id: 1
keys[0]: key1
keys[1]: keya
rec.id: 2
keys[0]: key2
keys[1]: keyb
rec.id: 3
keys[0]: key3
keys[1]: keyc
{key1,keya,key2,keyb,key3,keyc}
```